# Выделять ли кавычками фразеологизм?

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, редактура, корректура

**Новое зрение оказалось настоящим проклятием, как и предупреждал Зельдушка — маг, которого все считали темным. Настолько, насколько может быть темным маг, который когда-то уложил всех магов Теплого моря «одной левой», в прямом смысле, потому что правая на тот момент была у него сломана.**

И ещё: что делать с *тремя магами* и запятой, застрявшей между *одной левой* и *прямым смыслом*?

Если что, парцелляцию можно гнать в шею, ибо не жалко.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Новое зрение оказалось настоящим проклятием, как и предупреждал Зельдушка — маг, которого все считали темным. **Темным настолько, насколько может быть маг, который когда-то уложил всех других чародеев (волшебников, волхвов) Теплого моря одной левой в прямом смысле слова, так как  правая на тот момент была у него сломана.**

Одной левой, в прямом смысле — это устойчивые выражения, которые в кавычки не заключаются.

Примеры

― Мальчишка! Да я тебя **одной левой!** [Семен Данилюк. Рублевая зона (2004)]

В глазах помутилось **в прямом смысле** слова. [Токарева Виктория. Своя правда // «Новый Мир», 2002]

Answer (score 1):

[**одной левой**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/278345/%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9)
*нареч. качеств.-обстоят. разг.*
Крайне небрежно; кое-как.

*Побороть **одной левой*** (справиться с кем-либо как бы шутя, легко, почти не прилагая усилий).
*А ожидает их встреча с Мойдодыром, который обладает крутым нравом и расправляется с грязнулями **одной левой**!*

- Словосочетание *одной левой* — устойчивое, в кавычках не нуждается.

[**буквально**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/751758)
**2. В прямом смысле**, действительно (разг.)

*В Индонезии **в прямом смысле** «обвалилась» фондовая биржа.*
*Билл Гейтс: криптовалюты приводят к смерти — **в прямом смысле.***

- Пунктуация для выражения "в прямом смысле" зависит от контекста.

Я увидела Ваш кусочек так (меняю трех магов на двух; исключаю "которого-который" и парцелляцию; добавляю акцент на "прямом смысле"):

**Новое зрение оказалось настоящим проклятием, как и предупреждал Зельдушка —  маг, которого все считали темным. Эта репутация** (или — это отношение) **не помешала ему уложить всех магов Теплого моря одной левой, — в прямом смысле, — потому что правая на тот момент была у него сломана.**

Answer (score 1):

***Новое зрение оказалось настоящим проклятием, как и предупреждал Зельдушка — маг, которого все считали темным. Настолько, насколько может быть темным маг, который когда-то уложил всех магов Теплого моря одной левой - в прямом смысле, потому что правая на тот момент была у него сломана.***

Если приложения физической силы не было, а маг "уложил" всех силой мастерства, то кавычки можно оставить, например,  при "уложил". А можно  и не оставлять.

**Вставную конструкцию** в конце предложения выделяем **или тире (смотри выше), или скобками**, ср.:

***Новое зрение оказалось настоящим проклятием, как и предупреждал Зельдушка — маг, которого все считали темным. Настолько, насколько может быть темным маг, который когда-то уложил всех магов Теплого моря одной левой (в прямом смысле, потому что правая на тот момент была у него сломана).***